# Get hexcode of html entities

Tags: php, flash, unicode, hex

I have a string as "`&euro;`".

I want to convert it to hex to get the value as `"\u20AC"` so that I can send it to flash.

Same for all currency symbol..

```
 &pound;  ->  \u00A3
 &dollar; ->  \u0024
 etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that `&dollar;` is not a [known entity in HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html). It is, however, in HTML 5, and, in PHP 5.4, you can call `html_entity_decode` with `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5` to decode it.

You have to decode the entity and only then convert it:

```
//assumes $str is in UTF-8 (or ASCII)
function foo($str) {
    $dec = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    //convert to UTF-16BE
    $enc = mb_convert_encoding($dec, "UTF-16BE", "UTF-8");
    $out = "";
    foreach (str_split($enc, 2) as $f) {
        $out .= "\\u" . sprintf("%04X", ord($f[0]) << 8 | ord($f[1]));
    }
    return $out;
}
```

If you want to replace only the entities, you can use `preg_replace_callback` to match the entities and then use `foo` as a callback.

```
function repl_only_ent($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/&[^;]+;/',
        function($m) { return foo($m[0]); },
    $str);
}

echo repl_only_ent("&euro;foobar &acute;");
```

gives:

```
\u20ACfoobar \u00B4
```

Comment: my php version is 5.1.6...its showing fatal error at mb_convert_encoding ...how can i get the value please....

Comment: @PRA You can use iconv instead of mbstring, if you wish. If you don't have iconv too, you'll have to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 manually.

Comment: i have tried iconv()  but i am unable to recognize the charset type to convert hex

Answer (score -1):

You might try the following function for string to hex conversion:

```
function strToHex($string) {
    $hex='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
    }
    return $hex;
}
```

From [Greg Winiarski](http://ditio.net/2008/11/04/php-string-to-hex-and-hex-to-string-functions/) which is the [fourth hit on Google](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=php%20to%20hex).

In combination with [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php). So something like this:

```
$currency_symbol = "&euro;";
$hex = strToHex(html_entity_decode($currency_symbol));
```

**This code is untested and therefore may require further modification to return the exact result you require**

Comment: -1 only works with code points <= U+00FF (fails with &euro;, for instance) and even then it doesn't add \u00. Plus, to convert a string to hex, there's bin2hex, no need for your function.

Comment: BTW, it will fail even more spectacularly in PHP 5.4, when the default for html_entity_decode becomes UTF-8 and not ISO-8859-1.