# htmlentites not working for emoji

Tags: php, html-entities, emoji

I am trying to show a characters html entity

```
echo htmlentities(htmlentities("&"));
//outputs &amp;
echo htmlentities(htmlentities("<"));
//outputs &lt;
```

but it does not seem to work with emoji

```
echo htmlentities(htmlentities(""));
//outputs
```

How can I get it to output `&#128526;`?

---

Edit:

I am trying to display a string input by the user with all of the html entities encoded.
`echo htmlentities(htmlentities($input))`

Example:
`"this & that " -> "this &amp; that &#128526;"`

Comment: Out of curiosity.. why do this at all? If you're outputting unicode there's no need for entities.

Comment: `echo htmlentities(htmlentities("&"));` outputs `&amp;amp;`

Comment: not if content-type is text/html. the first &amp; gets converted to &

Comment: @TonyBrix no, your browser displays it as `&amp;` but it is not converted, check source of the page

Comment: It is converted to the user they only see &amp;

Comment: @Evert I am trying to display the html entity code to the user

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for regular HTML entities, UTF-8 emoticons (and other utf stuff) as well as regular strings of course.

I was just having trouble with empty string value, so I had to put this condition into the function.

```
function entities( $string ) {
    $stringBuilder = "";
    $offset = 0;

    if ( empty( $string ) ) {
        return "";
    }

    while ( $offset >= 0 ) {
        $decValue = ordutf8( $string, $offset );
        $char = unichr($decValue);

        $htmlEntited = htmlentities( $char );
        if( $char != $htmlEntited ){
            $stringBuilder .= $htmlEntited;
        } elseif( $decValue >= 128 ){
            $stringBuilder .= "&#" . $decValue . ";";
        } else {
            $stringBuilder .= $char;
        }
    }

    return $stringBuilder;
}

// source - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php#109812
function ordutf8($string, &$offset) {
    $code = ord(substr($string, $offset,1));
    if ($code >= 128) {        //otherwise 0xxxxxxx
        if ($code < 224) $bytesnumber = 2;                //110xxxxx
        else if ($code < 240) $bytesnumber = 3;        //1110xxxx
        else if ($code < 248) $bytesnumber = 4;    //11110xxx
        $codetemp = $code - 192 - ($bytesnumber > 2 ? 32 : 0) - ($bytesnumber > 3 ? 16 : 0);
        for ($i = 2; $i <= $bytesnumber; $i++) {
            $offset ++;
            $code2 = ord(substr($string, $offset, 1)) - 128;        //10xxxxxx
            $codetemp = $codetemp*64 + $code2;
        }
        $code = $codetemp;
    }
    $offset += 1;
    if ($offset >= strlen($string)) $offset = -1;
    return $code;
}

// source - http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php#88611
function unichr($u) {
    return mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($u) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
}

/* ---- */

var_dump( entities( "&" ) ) . "\n";
var_dump( entities( "<" ) ) . "\n";
var_dump( entities( "" ) ) . "\n";
var_dump( entities( "☚" ) ) . "\n";
var_dump( entities( "" ) ) . "\n";
var_dump( entities( "A" ) ) . "\n";
var_dump( entities( "Hello  world" ) ) . "\n";
var_dump( entities( "this & that " ) ) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

`$emoji = "\xF0\x9F\x98\x8E";` // its your emoji

I get this callback from  [convert unicode to html entities hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280200/convert-unicode-to-html-entities-hex)

```
$hex = preg_replace_callback('/[\x{80}-\x{10FFFF}]/u', function ($m) {
    $char = current($m);
    $utf = iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4', $char);
    return sprintf("&#x%s;", ltrim(strtoupper(bin2hex($utf)), "0"));
}, $emoji);

echo $hex;
```

`echo json_encode(("\xF0\x9F\x98\x8E"));` // its decoded. htmlentities doesn't work with it.

Is this OK ?

Comment: This doesn't work for regular html entities. The string I am trying to convert is input from the user so I don't know if it will be "" or "&" or "A". I would need a function that takes any input and outputs a string with html entities encoded

Comment: The input could also be a string with more than one character

Comment: How about to use something like this instead of htmlentities ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php#48861 you may need to make a benchmark. But it looks OK.

Comment: Btw, it is not possible to sanitize these input with html_special_chars or htmlentities check this out. https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.18/ext/standard/tests/strings/get_html_translation_table_basic1.phpt it is table using for htmlentities and special chars

Answer (score 4):

`htmlentities` documentation states that

> all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are
>   translated into these entities.

Your emoji does not have an equivalent like `&lt;` is for `<`, so it doesn't get converted. `&#128526;` is just an HTML code, not an HTML entity.

```
function htmlEntitiesOrCode($string) {
    //try htmlentities first
    $result = htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");

    //if the output is different from input, an entity was returned
    if ($result != $string) {
        return $result;
    }

    //get the html code
    $offset = 0;
    $code = ord(substr($string, $offset,1));
    if ($code >= 128) {
        if ($code < 224) {
            $bytesnumber = 2;
        } else if ($code < 240) {
            $bytesnumber = 3;
        } else if ($code < 248) {
            $bytesnumber = 4;
        }
        $codetemp = $code - 192 - ($bytesnumber > 2 ? 32 : 0) - ($bytesnumber > 3 ? 16 : 0);
        for ($i = 2; $i <= $bytesnumber; $i++) {
            $offset ++;
            $code2 = ord(substr($string, $offset, 1)) - 128;
            $codetemp = $codetemp*64 + $code2;
        }
        $code = $codetemp;
    }
    $offset += 1;
    if ($offset >= strlen($string)) {
        $offset = -1;
    }

    $result = "&#" . $code;
    return $result;
}
```

HTML code function taken from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php#109812