# Convert emoji to html code or display emoji as html

Tags: php, emoji

I want to covert emoji  to html `&#128512;` and display html code not emoji in my website, i use `htmlentities("");` but not working at all. How to display emoji as html code in my website or convert it?

Comment: Something like `&amp;#128512;` ?

Comment: yeah i want to display it but my website is display emoji instead code..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956163/htmlentites-not-working-for-emoji

Answer (score 9):

```
$utf32  = mb_convert_encoding( "", 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8' );
$hex4 = bin2hex($utf32);
$dec = hexdec($hex4);
echo "&#$dec;";        // 
echo "&amp;#$dec;";    // &#128512;
```