# Split emojis’s string in PHP

Tags: php, emoji

I have a string:

```
$string = '‍♂️';
```

And i want to split in:

```
$array = ['1F602', '1F9DCU-200D-2642-FE0F'];
```

How can i do it?

I have already try to use some functions but they doesn’t works because they doesn’t split properly emojis with more then one unicode.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am really not in this topic, and I can't identify the code of those symbols based on this: https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html. But: I see three glyphs, but your array contains two elements. What is your logic behind this split?

Comment: @ZorgoZ if you try to select the second and the third emoji you can see that actualy they are one emoji symbol.

Comment: My original message: https://imgur.com/gallery/EsGYI7y

Comment: Looking at the string using code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35050002/5159168 it does not seem to be two "items". https://3v4l.org/DBs9Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to write the code for splitting emojis using an emoji-unicode *dictionary* but fortunately the code already **exists**.

This [repo](https://github.com/aaronpk/emoji-detector-php) contains everything you need.

You can either use it directly or explore the code and take what you want.